# How to send extra data using NavigationStack with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have three `views` A,B and C. User can navigate from A to B and from A to C. User can navigate from B to C. Now I want to differentiate if the user have come from A to C or from B to C so I was looking in how to pass extra data in NavigationStack which can help me differentiate

Below is my code

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SampleApp: App {
    
    @State private var path: NavigationPath = .init()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $path){
                A(path: $path)
                    .navigationDestination(for: ViewOptions.self) { option in
                        option.view($path)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    enum ViewOptions {
        case caseB
        case caseC
        @ViewBuilder func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationPath>) -> some View{
            switch self{
            case .caseB:
                B(path: path)
            case .caseC:
                C(path: path)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct A: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("A")
            Button {
                path.append(SampleApp.ViewOptions.caseB)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to B")
            }
            Button {
                path.append(SampleApp.ViewOptions.caseC)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to C")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct B: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("B")
            Button {
                path.append(SampleApp.ViewOptions.caseC)
            } label: {
                Text("Go to C")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct C: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("C")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you expanded `ViewOptions` to represent all views in the path (including view A) you could use an array of `[ViewOptions]` instead of a NavigationPath object, and that would allow you to interoogate your hierarchy? i.e., the last item in the array is your current view, but the second-to-last will be the view before that.

Comment: Not sure I understand @ScottM

Comment: printing your path at given time should tell you the where you have come from

Comment: @Pritish NavigationPath() can represent a variety of view states being pushed onto the stack. However, if you're always pushing exactly the same type of data (e.g., always using a `ViewOptions` struct, you can declare `@State var path: [ViewOptions]` instead of using a NavigationPath object. If you do this, then you can look inside that array to see the objects that make up the current path. NavigationPath has a few collection-liek methods, but you can't look inside it in the same way as you can with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the second-to-last item in the `path` property to learn what the previous screen was.

To do this, it's easier to use an actual array of `ViewOptions` as the path, instead of a `NavigationPath`.

For example:

```
struct SampleApp: App {
    // Use your own ViewOptions enum, instead of NavigationPath
    @State private var path: [ViewOptions] = []
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $path){
                A(path: $path)
                    .navigationDestination(for: ViewOptions.self) { option in
                        option.view($path)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct C: View {
    @Binding var path: [ViewOptions]

    var previousView: ViewOptions? {
        path
            .suffix(2) // Get the last 2 elements of the path
            .first     // Get the first of those last 2 elements
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("C")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, a `NavigationPath` is nothing more than a type-erased array. It can be used to build a `NavigationStack` quickly without having to worry that all destination values have to match the same type. Since as you're controlling the navigation flow with your own type `ViewOptions`, it makes no sense to use `NavigationPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "pass extra data in `NavigationStack`" you can pass data in a `NavigationRouter`. It gives you much more control

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
//Simplify the repetitive code
typealias NavSource = SampleApp.ViewOptions
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct NavigationRouter{
    var path: [NavSource] = .init()
    ///Adds the provided View to the stack
    mutating func goTo(view: NavSource){
        path.append(view)
    }
    ///Searches the stack for the `View`, if the view is `nil`, the stack returns to root, if the `View` is not found the `View` is presented from the root
    mutating func bactrack(view: NavSource?){
        guard let view = view else{
            path.removeAll()
            return
        }
        //Look for the desired view
        while !path.isEmpty && path.last != view{
            path.removeLast()
        }
        //If the view wasn't found  add it to the stack
        if path.isEmpty{
            goTo(view: view)
        }
    }
    ///Identifies the previous view in the stack, returns nil if the previous view is the root
    func identifyPreviousView() -> NavSource?{
        //1 == current view, 2 == previous view
        let idx = path.count - 2
        //Make sure idx is valid index
        guard idx >= 0 else{
            return nil
        }
        //return the view
        return path[idx]
    }
}
```

Once you have access to the router in the `View`s you can  adjust accordingly.

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SampleApp: View {
    @State private var router: NavigationRouter = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.path){
            A(router: $router)
            //Have the root handle the type
            .navigationDestination(for: NavSource.self) { option in
                option.view($router)
            }
        }
    }
    //Create an `enum` so you can define your options
    //Conform to all the required protocols
    enum ViewOptions: Codable, Equatable, Hashable{
        case caseB
        case caseC
        //If you need other arguments add like this
        case unknown(String)
        //Assign each case with a `View`
        @ViewBuilder func view(_ path: Binding<NavigationRouter>) -> some View{
            switch self{
            case .caseB:
                B(router: path)
            case .caseC:
                C(router: path)
            case .unknown(let string):
                Text("View for \(string.description) has not been defined")
            }
        }
    }
}
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct A: View {
    @Binding var router: NavigationRouter
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button {
                router.goTo(view: .caseB)
            } label: {
                Text("To B")
            }
            Button {
                router.goTo(view: .caseC)
            } label: {
                Text("To C")
            }
        }.navigationTitle("A")
    }
}
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct B: View {
    @Binding var router: NavigationRouter
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button {
                router.goTo(view: .caseC)
            } label: {
                Text("Hello")
            }
            
        }.navigationTitle("B")
    }
}
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct C: View {
    @Binding var router: NavigationRouter
    //Identify changes based on previous View
    var fromA: Bool{
        //nil is the root
        router.identifyPreviousView() == nil
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Welcome\(fromA ? " Back" : "" )")

            Button {
                //Append to the path the enum value
                router.bactrack(view: router.identifyPreviousView())
            } label: {
                Text("Back")
            }
            Button {
                //Append to the path the enum value
                router.goTo(view: .unknown("\"some other place\""))
            } label: {
                Text("Next")
            }
            
        }.navigationTitle("C")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```